# JAVA Queue - Unit testing failed

Tags: java, unit-testing, queue

Okay, I am trying to unit test my DSAQueue class and it is showing that, my **isEmpty()**, **isFull()** and **dequeue()** methods failed.

Following is my code for DSAQueue. 
I think there is something wrong with my **Dequeue()** method, I am unable to figure it out on where did I go wrong. 
Please help me find out.
THANK YOU! in advance!

Here is my code:

```
public class DSAQueue {
    int count;
    Object[] queue;
    public static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;


    public DSAQueue(){
        count = 0;
        queue = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    public DSAQueue(int maxCapacity){
        count = 0;
        queue = new Object[maxCapacity];
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        boolean empty = (count==0);
        return empty; 
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        boolean full = (count == queue.length);
        return full;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object value){

        if (isFull())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Queue is full");
        else
            queue[count] = value;

        count++;
    }

    public Object dequeue(){
        Object frontVal;
        frontVal = peek();
        count--;
        return frontVal;
    }

    public Object peek(){
        Object frontVal;
        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Queue is empty");
        else
            frontVal = queue[0];

        return frontVal; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, your `dequeue()` doesn't do what it name implies:

- It does `peek()` to get the first item.
- It reduces the `count`, so this stays consistent.
- However, it never modifies the underlying array `queue`. The element just remains in there.

Comment: Oh! well but how do I fix it? Sorry I am new to queue. Could you please elaborate it a bit? How am I supposed to modify the underlying array queue?

Comment: Just think what the operation needs to do, and you'll find the answer. What you need is a rather basic array operation...

Comment: The dequeue operation *does* update the internal representation, but it removes from the wrong end.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation doesn't fit a queue data structure indeed. Your head of the queue is in in position 0, but you add/remove items to/from the tail. You should be enqueuing to the tail, and dequeuing from the head.

If you want to keep using an array (which is reasonable given that the queue has to be bounded), consider using it as a [Circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Another option is to implement your queue as a linked list.